# exactextractr::exact_extract just keeping numeric value of categorical raster (and not the labels)

Tags: raster, r, terra, exact-extract

I converted a polygon to raster to then be able to apply exact_extract the most common value in another polygon of interest (areas_interest in the example below). However, the final product returns numeric values. Is there a way for exact_extract to return both the numeric value and its label?

I checked that when I plot object out below, it displays the labels.

```
# read-in polygon 
polygon <- vect(paste0(gis, '/barc/soil_characteristics/soil_salinity/soil_salinity.shp'))

# convert polygon to raster 
raster_matrix <- rast(polygon, 1000, 1000) # creating a 1000 x 1000 cells raster 
out <- rasterize(polygon, raster_matrix, field = 'CLASS')
plot(out)  

# process data 
soil_salinity <- exactextractr::exact_extract(out, areas_interest, fun = 'mode', 
                                              append_cols = 'UID')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a raster, as you can intersect the polygons and compute area and aggregate these. For example:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
p <- as.polygons(ext(v[1:2]), crs=crs(v))

i <- intersect(v, p)
i$area <- expanse(i, unit="km")
d <- data.frame(i)
a <- aggregate(d[, "area", drop=FALSE], d[,"NAME_2", drop=FALSE], sum)

a[order(a[,2], decreasing=T), ]
#      NAME_2      area
#1   Clervaux 312.28321
#7      Wiltz 222.32572
#2   Diekirch 218.67403
#5    Redange 117.69407
#6    Vianden  76.20041
#4     Mersch  57.61180
#3 Echternach  25.46339
```

Here is an approach in which you first create rasters (I would not recommend it).

```
x <- rast(v, res=0.01)
x <- rasterize(v, x, "NAME_2") 
a <- cellSize(x, unit="km")
a <- mask(a, p)
z <- zonal(a, x, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to preserve the polygons of areas_interest, though. My understanding is this is creating a new, aggregate area. My question was more about how to preserve the value labels in the exact_extract process. I see how your approach keeps the labels, but not sure it is keeping the areas_interest.